# How to rearrange this doubly infinite sum for a diffeomorphism using the existence of a first integral?

Tags: sequences-and-series, differential-geometry, recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

Let's take two diffeomorphisms $F,G: \mathbb{R}^{n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $x  \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $x^{n} = F^{n}(x)$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. Suppose that $F$ has a
first  integral, i.e. there exists a function $I: \mathbb{R}^{n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ such that $I(x) = I(F(x))$.

Suppose that I have a function $H(x)$ (that arises in the theory of invariant manifolds) that is defined to be

\begin{equation}
H(x) = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} { \langle DF^{n}(x^{-n})G(x^{-n-1}), I(x) \rangle }
\label{one}
\end{equation}

where the angle brackets indicate inner product, and $D$ is the derivative. I would like to manipulate the above expression for $H(x)$ into the following form:

$$H(x)= \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} { \langle G(x^{n-1}), \nabla I(x^{n}) \rangle }.$$

Now I can use that $I(x) = I(F^{n}(x^{-n}))$, and $\nabla I(x^{n}) = \nabla_{x^{n}} I(x^{n+1}) = \frac{\partial I(F(x^{n})}{\partial F}DF(x^{n})$, with $\langle Ax,y \rangle = \langle x, A^{T}y\rangle$ to make some progress, but I still can't get the desired form.

I would appreciate any step by step help.

Comment: Something having to do with the Melnikov method? Honestly I fail to see why we should believe that it should be possible to obtain the identity.

Comment: Yes, it is indeed the Melnikov method. Anyway, I have actually managed to derive the identity. I will post it in a minute. @Jonas

Comment: Great, it would be nice to see it.

Comment: See my derivation below. @Jonas

Comment: Nice "trick". --

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $\nabla I(x) = (DF(x))^{T} \nabla I(x^{1}) = (DF(x^{n-1}...DF(x))^{T} \nabla I(x^{n}) = (DF^{n}(x))^{T} \nabla I(x^{n})$.

Hence we have

$$ \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} {\langle DF^{n}(x^{-n}) G(x^{-n-1}), \nabla I(x) \rangle} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} {\langle  G(x^{-n-1}), (DF^{n}(x^{-n})^{T}\nabla I(x) \rangle} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} {\langle  G(x^{n-1}), (DF^{-n}(x^{n})^{T}\nabla I(x) \rangle} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} {\langle  G(x^{n-1}), (DF^{-n}(x^{n})^{T} (DF^{n}(x))^{T}\nabla I(x^{n}) \rangle} = \sum_{n= -\infty}^{n= \infty} {\langle  G(x^{n-1}), (DF^{n}(x) DF^{-n}(x^{n}))^{T}\nabla I(x^{n}) \rangle} = \sum_{n =  -\infty}^{n = \infty} {\langle G(x^{n-1}), \nabla I(x^{n}) \rangle }$$

as required.